# Why won't my taken picture display on my imageview

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, photo

I don't know why but my taken image doesn't display on my imageview. If i try to display an image that was already in my app ( in the mipmap folder for example ) it will display that, but it won't display an image I took. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
private File imageFile;
private static final int PHOTO_TAKEN = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_taker);

    addSnapButtonListener();
}

private void addSnapButtonListener(){
    Button snapBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera_button);

    snapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            File picturesDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            imageFile = new File(picturesDirectory, "passpoints_image");

            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
            startActivityForResult(i, PHOTO_TAKEN);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int reqC, int resC, Intent data) {

    if(reqC == PHOTO_TAKEN){
       // Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    //    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        if(photo != null){
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.taken_image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.unable_to_set_photo_file, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

I tried a couple of different methods to get my taken image ( as you can see with the commented out code ) but whenever I take the picture and I look at the imageview it is still blank.

This also happens when I try to display an image from the gallery. Is it an issue with my phone?

Edit: also, the imagepath does get registered because I can retrieve it and display it in a toast or the log, so I don't believe that that's part of the issue.

Comment: Did you confirm that everything is working as expected in your activity? Try adding logs. If your Bitmap is being returned as null, then when you set it it won't show anything in the view. But to eliminate that possibility use another device.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

That will return `null`, as there will be no extra with that name.

This code, that you have commented out, is closer:

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

But, you need to retain `imageFile`, as your activity may be destroyed or your process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground. And, `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+ devices, once you move your `targetSdkVersion` to 24 or higher. Plus, do not call `decode...()` on `BitmapFactory` on the main application thread, as your UI will freeze while that disk I/O and computation is going on.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.1/Camera/FileProvider) (from [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), FWIW), demonstrates using `FileProvider` instead of `Uri.fromFile()` and retaining the path using `onSaveInstanceState()`. In my case, I show the image via `ACTION_VIEW` instead of loading into an `ImageView`:

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2008-2016 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class CameraContentDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String EXTRA_FILENAME=
    "com.commonsware.android.camcon.EXTRA_FILENAME";
  private static final String FILENAME="CameraContentDemo.jpeg";
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private static final String AUTHORITY=
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider";
  private static final String PHOTOS="photos";
  private File output=null;
  private Uri outputUri=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      output=new File(new File(getFilesDir(), PHOTOS), FILENAME);

      if (output.exists()) {
        output.delete();
      }
      else {
        output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      }
    }
    else {
      output=(File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME);
    }

    outputUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, output);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        ClipData clip=
          ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "A photo", outputUri);

        i.setClipData(clip);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList=
          getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
          String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
          grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
      }

      startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME, output);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        i.setDataAndType(outputUri, "image/jpeg");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I were going to load this into an `ImageView`, I would use [an image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).